# How to align my buttons at the same height?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to align my buttons at the same height, so that they all drop down when the text pushes one of them down. my go-to solution doesn't seem to work.

**Have a look at my code:**

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
        <title>Placeholder</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
        <style type="text/css"></style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-groei">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="container-groei-section">
                    <h2>Placement</h2>
                    <p>Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement text
                            Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement text
                            Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement text</p> <br>
                       <div class="med-linebreak"></div>
                    <div class="button-placement-groei">
                        <a href="#">
                        <div class="read-more-button">
                            <div class="read-more-button-text">Read more</div>
                        </div></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="container-groei-section">
                    <h2>Placement</h2>
                    <p>Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement texttextJust some placement text
                            Just some placement textJustlacement text</p> <br>
                       <div class="med-linebreak"></div>
                    <div class="button-placement-groei">
                        <a href="#">
                        <div class="read-more-button">
                            <div class="read-more-button-text">Read more</div>
                        </div></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="container-groei-section">
                    <h2>Placement</h2>
                    <p>Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement text
                            Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement text
                            Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement text
                            Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement text</p> <br>
                       <div class="med-linebreak"></div>
                    <div class="button-placement-groei">
                        <a href="#">
                        <div class="read-more-button">
                            <div class="read-more-button-text">Read more</div>
                        </div></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="container-groei-section">
                    <h2>Placement</h2>
                    <p>Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement text
                            Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement text
                            Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement text
                            Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement text</p> <br>
                       <div class="med-linebreak"></div>
                    <div class="button-placement-groei">
                        <a href="#">
                        <div class="read-more-button">
                            <div class="read-more-button-text">Read more</div>
                        </div></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="container-groei-section">
                    <h2>Placement</h2>
                    <p>Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement</p> <br>
                       <div class="med-linebreak"></div>
                    <div class="button-placement-groei">
                        <a href="#">
                        <div class="read-more-button">
                            <div class="read-more-button-text">Read more</div>
                        </div></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="container-groei-section">
                    <h2>Placement</h2>
                    <p>Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement text
                            Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement text
                            Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement text
                            Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement text</p> <br>
                       <div class="med-linebreak"></div>
                    <div class="button-placement-groei">
                        <a href="#">
                        <div class="read-more-button">
                            <div class="read-more-button-text">Read more</div>
                        </div></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**CSS**

```
.container-groei {
    max-width: 1600px; 
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 150px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.10);
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.10);
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.10);
}   

.container-groei-section {
    min-height: 550px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.container-groei-section p {
    font-size: 16px;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.container-groei-section h2 {
    color: #0E8DBD;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
}

.button-placement-groei {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.read-more-button {
    background: #00aeef;
    border-radius: 11px;
}

.read-more-button-text {
    font-family: 'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,Lucida,sans-serif;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 21px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

I probably messed something up with my CSS, but can't seem to figure out what.
What I'm looking for is for the buttons to remain at the same height at any time, so that there is white space between the button and the paragraph that contains less words than the others. An easy solution would be to give the paragraph a max height, but this just creates more problems.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What you need is a grid system instead of just columns of bootstrap that's seperating the content in 3 different columns but the alignment of the button divs get uneven. Instead of doing that, you can make 2X3 sized CSS grid, in which the first row contains your text part and the bottom row contains the buttons.

Comment: Since, no one has answered this question rate my answer up or mark it if you found it helpful. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you should make use of CSS Grid instead of bootstrap's fixed column grid system if what you want to achieve is the alignment of content at the same level. But here's a fix for your code, all you have to do is take the button out of your container-groei section and adjust the height of the section.

But if you want your button group to be inside the section, you will need to make use of absolute positioning for the buttons, thats the only other way of achieving this. But I'd still recommend you to checkout CSS Grids.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
        <title>Placeholder</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
        <style type="text/css">
          .container-groei {
    max-width: 1600px; 
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 150px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.10);
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.10);
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.10);
}   

.container-groei-section {
    min-height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.container-groei-section p {
    font-size: 16px;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.container-groei-section h2 {
    color: #0E8DBD;
    padding-bottom: px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
}

.button-placement-groei {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.read-more-button {
    background: #00aeef;
    border-radius: 11px;
}

.read-more-button-text {
    font-family: 'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,Lucida,sans-serif;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 21px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-groei">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="container-groei-section">
                    <h2>Placement</h2>
                    <p>Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement text
                            Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement text
                            Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement text</p> <br>
                       <div class="med-linebreak"></div>

                </div>
                <div class="button-placement-groei">
                        <a href="#">
                        <div class="read-more-button">
                            <div class="read-more-button-text">Read more</div>
                        </div></a>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="container-groei-section">
                    <h2>Placement</h2>
                    <p>Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement texttextJust some placement text
                            Just some placement textJustlacement text</p> <br>
                       <div class="med-linebreak"></div>

                </div>
                <div class="button-placement-groei">
                        <a href="#">
                        <div class="read-more-button">
                            <div class="read-more-button-text">Read more</div>
                        </div></a>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="container-groei-section">
                    <h2>Placement</h2>
                    <p>Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement text
                            Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement text
                            Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement text
                            Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement text</p> <br>
                       <div class="med-linebreak"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="button-placement-groei">
                        <a href="#">
                        <div class="read-more-button">
                            <div class="read-more-button-text">Read more</div>
                        </div></a>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="container-groei-section">
                    <h2>Placement</h2>
                    <p>Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement text
                            Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement text
                            Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement text
                            Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement text</p> <br>
                       <div class="med-linebreak"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="button-placement-groei">
                        <a href="#">
                        <div class="read-more-button">
                            <div class="read-more-button-text">Read more</div>
                        </div></a>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="container-groei-section">
                    <h2>Placement</h2>
                    <p>Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement</p> <br>
                       <div class="med-linebreak"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="button-placement-groei">
                        <a href="#">
                        <div class="read-more-button">
                            <div class="read-more-button-text">Read more</div>
                        </div></a>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="container-groei-section">
                    <h2>Placement</h2>
                    <p>Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement text
                            Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement text
                            Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement text
                            Just some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement textJust some placement text</p> <br>
                       <div class="med-linebreak"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="button-placement-groei">
                        <a href="#">
                        <div class="read-more-button">
                            <div class="read-more-button-text">Read more</div>
                        </div></a>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```